# How to install Airflow slave/client without the master/server?

Tags: python, workflow, batch-processing, job-scheduling, airflow

I've installed airflow onto my server as per the documentations instructions [here](https://pythonhosted.org/airflow/start.html).

The installation looks to contain both the master (server) and slave (client).

How to install the slave/client component of Airflow on another computer? Or does each installation need to contain both the server and client?

Comment: Figured this out. The workers (clients) only need to have airflow and celery installed whilst the server needs to have airflow,celery and a db such as mysql if you use the celeryexecutor.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are referring as client. In my environment Airflow WebServer , Scheduler and worker (CeleryExecutor) are all installed in same server and those components are started as part of init scripts.

Comment: To be specific, by client I mean worker. I have one core machine running certain scripts and another VM running other scripts, so I would assume you just use celery executor between the two. In your personal application, are you also using separate VMs?

Comment: In my case, all airflow services (web server,scheduler,worker) running in same physical host. DAGs are being checked out directly from git in the same server.(in respective directory). But based on the need we can have workers running in more than one hosts with same airflow config file.